# Text fades in/out on new bootstrap carousel slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have built a bootstrap carousel that changes a p tag's text depending on the active carousel slide. How would I go about fading that text out when a slide's interval is about to end, and fade in the new, altered text upon the new slide becoming active?

Here is the jQuery (JSFiddle example below):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
});

var arrMessages = ["Text for Image 1 class!", 
                   "Text for Image 2 class!",
                   "Text for Image 3 class!"]

var $msg = $("#sticksCarouselMessage");
$('#sticksCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    var text = "", 
         $active = $('div.active'),
         index = $('div.item').index($active);

    $msg.text(arrMessages[index]);

});
```

});

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/CharlieMcShane/hja32vjn/

Comment: try using this https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ , just add the fade-in and fade-out class to the <p> tag, and you are set to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut similar to this:

```
$msg.fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $msg.text(arrMessages[index]);
}).fadeIn('fast');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
  });

  var arrMessages = ["Text for Image 1 class!",
    "Text for Image 2 class!",
    "Text for Image 3 class!"
  ]

  var $msg = $("#sticksCarouselMessage");
  $('#sticksCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    $msg.fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $msg.text(arrMessages[index]);
    }).fadeIn('fast');
    
    var text = "",
      $active = $('div.active'),
      index = $('div.item').index($active);
  });
});
```

```css
/*-- Carousel bars --*/

.carousel-indicators.middle {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators.middle li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}


/*-- Carousel Next/Prev --*/

.carousel .carousel-control {
  top: 50%;
}

.carousel .left.carousel-control:after {
  content: "<";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.carousel .right.carousel-control:after {
  content: ">";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*-- Carousel Pre-text --*/

#sticksCarouselMessage {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Carousel Slider -->
<div class="carousel slide" id="sticksCarousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators middle">
    <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#sticksCarousel"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#sticksCarousel"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#sticksCarousel"></li>
  </ol>

  <section class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img alt="blah" class="image1" src="http://www.slidesjs.com/img/example-slide-350-3.jpg" style="width:100%;">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img alt="blah" class="image2" src="http://www.slidesjs.com/img/example-slide-350-3.jpg" style="width:100%;">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img alt="blah" class="image3" src="http://www.slidesjs.com/img/example-slide-350-3.jpg" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Carousel Next/Prev -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#sticksCarousel"></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#sticksCarousel"></a>
</div>

<!-- Carousel Pre-text -->
<p id="sticksCarouselMessage">Text for Image 1 class!</p>
```

Comment: Such a simple approach. This will work brilliantly, really appreciate the time mate!

Answer (score 1):

Use keyframes to animate the text:

```css
@keyframes myText {
  0%  { opacity: 0; }
  5% { opacity: .5; }
  10% { opacity: 1; }
  90% { opacity: 1; }
  95% { opacity: .5; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
#sticksCarouselMessage {
  animation: myText 2s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the CSS work around! Never used keyframes within CSS before, so I should experiment around with them sometime! Thanks again!

Comment: This works great when the carousel rotates automatically but as soon as you mix that with the manual click through the slides the animation seems to get out of rhythm and occasionally "fades" multiple times on the same text. The reason I suppose is that the CSS animation is not tied to the slide change but is on a 2s timer regardless if the slide has changed or not.